# How to validate three check boxes with reactive forms module?

Tags: angular, validation, material-ui

This should be relatively easy, not sure why I am struggling.

I have three check-boxes and I want to make sure the user clicks one and only one. So the validator should check that any of the other two boxes have been checked and prevent another selection. It should make sure at least one is checked.

I have tried using a custom validator, but you can only pass a control in. I need something that checks all the boxes for validation.

````
<form class="example-section" [formGroup]="queryType">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="artist" formControlName="artist">Artist</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="album" formControlName="album">Album</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="track" formControlName="track">Track</mat-checkbox>
</form>```
````

```
 export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  filteredSearchItems: Observable<SearchResult[]>;
  isLoading = false;
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  queryType: FormGroup;
  disabled: boolean = false;
  artist: boolean;
  album: boolean;
  track: boolean;



constructor(private searchService: SearchService, private fb: 
  FormBuilder) {
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
  searchInput: new FormControl(null)
});
this.queryType = this.fb.group({
 'artist': new FormControl(false,[CustomValidators.validateQuery]),
  'album': new FormControl(false,[CustomValidators.validateQuery]),
  'track': new FormControl(false,[CustomValidators.validateQuery])
});
```

}

```
export class CustomValidators {

    static validateQuery(control: FormGroup): { [s: string]: boolean } 
       {//not sure how to pass in all boxes


   for(const con of control.controls) { // somewhere here is the answer
            if(con.value) {
            return { alreadyChecked: true} 
            }
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There 2 possible solutions for it.

> 1.) You can use a radio button instead of checkbox, that way you can only select either one of those 3 options.
>
> 2.) If you really want to use the checkbox. You can implement it like this. Have also created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-checkbox-form)** for your reference

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
              formControlName="artist"
              [disabled]="album || track">Artist</mat-checkbox>   // This will be disabled when album or track is already checked

<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
              formControlName="album"
              [disabled]="artist || track">Album</mat-checkbox>   // This will be disabled when artist or track is already checked

<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
              formControlName="track"
              [disabled]="artist || album">Track</mat-checkbox>   // This will be disabled when artist or album is already checked.
```

With that, the user can only check one item from those 3 options.

**NOTE:**

- You should decide whether you'll use a Template Driven Form [(ngModel)] or Reactive Form Module (formControlName) since you can't merge those two inside an input tag.

Comment: @godhar That's great! good thing it helps. mind if you'll upvote it ? That would mean a lot. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Actually this is a naf way of doing it.